# Updating Bulk Nulls using ID

Tags: null

I have 20000 records, and after importing them into a table I have a lot of columns that are null. I just want to add random numbers into these columns.. I want to select about 1000 columns at a time using the Job_ID number (Auto Incremented Number), and make the another column in the same table a number 1 or a random bit of text like "fixed"

How do I do this? I'm a big noob so go easy..

Comment: which database system are you using? You just need to set these values during importing... but we cannot help you unless you provide more details...

Comment: I’m using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2005,

Answer (score 1):

You have probbably SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
  row1,
  row2, 
  row3
FROM table1
```

and some of row*s are NULL and you want to replace that with some default value, you can do that by:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(row1, 'row1default') as row1, 
  COALESCE(row2, 'row2default') as row2, 
  COALESCE(row3, 'row3default') as row3 
FROM table1
```